# How do I model an arch gate made from big bricks?

Tags: modeling

[image: These blocks above the arch perfectly align with the bricks on the side]How do I model these connecting bricks with 5 edges while keeping them aligning with the curvature of the arch and the side of the bricks with 4 edges? I tried to recreating that by cutting these shapes on a plane, but this solution is not accurate enough. On the picture you can also see that the grooves are slightly beveled.

Comment: Like this? https://i.imgur.com/9VZpb3L.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After sleeping on it, I think what you need is an arch made of bricks that take the same length of the arc, and snap to the coordinates of the horizontal bricks. Since this is a modeling question, not geometry nodes, here's a manual solution:

1. Spawn a circle with 16-32 vertices (I'm doing 24)

[image]

2. Create yourself lines aligned to the grid, which will represent the brick layers. Then $\color{#888}{█0█}$ *hover mouse cursor* over the circle <kbd>L</kbd> to select it, <kbd>`I`</kbd> to inset, and align the new loop so that the red edge ends at the green line:

[image]

3. In ortographic mode you can zoom in and easily adjust using <kbd>S</kbd> scaling, so that the positioning will be good even by perfectionist standards.
4. Press <kbd>`I`</kbd> again, and drag it to create roughly a square on the first layer of bricks:

[image]

5. You can now remove the bottom of the circle, and the right side, because later you will mirror it:

[image]

6. We have one vertex at an intersection of two straight lines and a circular loop, created in points 2-3, now travel along the circular loop and using <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> shortcut, slide the vertices to align them in the same way, each time going one brick layer higher:

[image]

7. Again like in p. 3. You may want to zoom in to align better. For the worst case of OCD-perfectionism combination, you can also round the Y coordinate in the <kbd>N</kbd> Numbers panel:

[image]

6. Select the middle loop and subdivide it, move each just created vertex to the connected vertex above (snap it), and then move it again, lock the $x$ axis and snap to the lower connected vertex:

[image]

7. Delete the outer loop, vertex at origin and guiding horizontal lines.
8. Move bottom edges to the left to make the brick longer like in the reference image:

[image]

9. If you want 2 bottom bricks to be long, you need to make sure the first from the bottom is entirely horizontal:

[image]

11. The rest is hopefully straight-forward:

[image]