# What is the fastest way to create the arch window inside the plane with a good topology?

Tags: modeling

[image]

What is the fastest way to create the arch window inside the plane with good topology?

I tried:

1. Create a plane. Do insert <kbd>I</kbd>
2. Split center square <kbd>Y</kbd>
3. Select 2 top vertexes, created arch bevel <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>, <kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd>
4. Do insert in the arch <kbd>I</kbd>
5. Bridge parts inside the arch to make a hole
6. Connect the arch to all other parts with a knife tool <kbd>K</kbd> and <kbd>F</kbd> key

Is there a faster way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. <kbd>⬆ Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>`I`</kbd> Circle. <kbd>F9</kbd>, set **Triangle** fill.
2. "Cast" modifier, "Cuboid" mode, Factor = 1. <kbd>⬆ Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> Apply the modifier.

[image][image][image]

3. <kbd>⭾ Tab</kbd>, <kbd>`I`</kbd> Inset, $\color{green}{█}\color{#888}{0█}$ *left click* to create overlapping vertices, <kbd>S</kbd> scale down to whatever size you need. Copy a coordinate of one of the vertices aligned with an axis to get the radius - here `0.5`:

[image]

4. Select top part of the inset (with or without center vert) and assign it to a vertex group.
5. Add another "Cast" modifier, this time in "Sphere" mode, also Factor 1, but Size set to the radius you measured (here `0.5`). The actual "Radius" field should be 0. Turn off "Size from radius" option.

[image][image][image]

6. Delete the center vertex:

[image]

See also: [How do I model an arch gate made from big bricks?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/283932/60486)

Comment: Enjoyed the detailed step by step instructions :). Me being lazy would've probably just posted the final topology result :).