# How to add a layer of stones straight across over the arch?

Tags: objects, 3d-printing

I have a model that needs to be 3D printed and I need to add a layer of stones straight across over the arch. What would be the best way to do this in Blender?

[image]

Comment: i know you are new here...but there were some "strange" rules for this site (maybe you should read the "how to ask" section) - one rule is: don't ask so called "opioned based questions" and every question with "what is the best way"...is 99,999% opioned based because there are nearly always many different ways how you can realize things in Blender. So i would change the question - if i were you. It is pretty obvious that your question might be closed if you don't change it.

Comment: Hi Stuart :). What have you tried to add the stones? Duplicated geometry, sculpting, displacement? :)

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: @Chris . Apologies, sorry my dyslexia got the better of me. It's changed :)

Comment: @jachymmichal Thanks for that Michal. The model is a 3D STL that I downloaded and there's no separate layers. I was thinking of going down the sculpting or the displacement route, but wondered which was the easiest option.

Comment: @jachymmichal Thanks for the heads up and the useful advice there. I've changed the title :)

Comment: Hey :). I'm a bit lazy, so I'd probably just duplicate some of the existing stones, and arrange them as the top row. Sculpting would then help with the details.

Comment: I think the answer is… Sculpt them in. Maybe you can cut out a portion of existing mesh and duplicate it, move up, and then sculpt a little so it's not visible it's copied, but other than that the question strikes me as "I've drawn 90% of my painting, how do I finish the rest?" For general advise how to create an arch like that: [How do I model an arch gate made from big bricks?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/283932/60486)