# How do you rotate a certain face to a 90 degree angle vertically?

Tags: modeling

[image: annyoing rotation problem image]

so, as you can see in the image, the highlighted edge is not at a 90-degree angle. I am trying to make an arch but I need that one face to go 90 degrees. I am trying to make an arch and this is 3d, the highlighted part is a face from a side view. I have made this by making a cube then extruding and rotating that one face then extruding from that face again. Please give me a solution to make that particular face at a 90-degree angle. Thank you!

Comment: It seems in your case pressing S, X, 0 keys will be good enough? Related: [How do I model an arch gate made from big bricks?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/283932/60486)

Comment: why don't you draw the expected result of your arch and show us a screenshot of it.